# Pull multiple Git repositories with EGit on Eclipse at once

Tags: eclipse, git, pull, repository

I have cloned ~60 git repositories and I would like to update the most of them with `git pull` through EGit. Not all, because some of them have uncommited or unstaged changes.

My first try was to select two repos in EGit (Git Repository Exploring view) but unfortunately this seems not to be possible, since the affecting button is disabled (context menu).

Does andbody know a good solution to update some repositories through Eclipse?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Juno. Sure, a shell script could solve this but I prefer Eclipse for this.

Comment: The select all/pull from the repo exploring perspective works fine for me in Juno. (As it always have)

Comment: @ptyx Interesting... Which version of EGit, JGit and Eclips are you using? I'll add detailed information about my setup later.

Comment: Selecting all projects in git perspective, pull via context menu works fine in Èclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the solution is too simple: one of my cloned repositories had no HEAD and therefore I cannot pull from it. All other repos had a HEAD revision and pulling from them works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the answer, using Kepler. This was a nightmare for me with 15 repos.
`Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->General->Keys`. Now scroll to Pull (make sure it's the egit one)
Set it to something like `Ctl-Shift-P`
Now in package explorer select the ones you want and press `Ctl-Shift-P`, done.